# websockets and javascript - transmitting name / value pairs

Tags: javascript, websocket

So there is a limit of 1 websocket connection per webpage in most browsers. Therefore, if I want my application to update several different items on a single page at the same time, I need to pass name/value pairs, e.g.:

```
number_of_notifications=5
latest_news_headline='Websockets are awesome!'
foo='bar'
```

My question is: what is the best cross-browser way to do this? The problem with simply sending variables as I showed above and then splitting them based on the '=' sign is that an equal sign in either the name or the value can break the script:

```
latest_news_headline='Websockets = awesome!'
```

My first thought was to transmit the name and value in base64 (in which case, I can use the = sign to delimit the data). Unfortunately, that's not supported in all browsers (I know that websockets aren't either, I'm actually using SockJS as a websocket emulator for the other browsers; the SockJS protocol, however, is identical to the websocket protocol, by design).

Comment: Why do you believe there is such limitation?

Comment: This may not be a physical limitation with the WebSocket protocol, but all browsers I'm aware support no more than 2 Websocket connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like stringified JSON is the obvious choice?